# why a string is added in wrong format to the razorview?

Tags: asp.net, razor

i'm trying to add a few classes to a listitem object in my html using razor and a helper method.

I defined a @functions{} section with a method :

```
public string AddClasses()
{
      return "classes=\"class1 class2\"";
}
```

when using in razor

```
<li @AddClasses()>tekst</li>
```

the result is:

```
<li class=""class1" class2&quot;">tekst</li>
```

what am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Razor automatically html encodes any string so it turns your `"` into `&quot;`.

To turn off the html encoding you need to use the `Html.Raw` method ([MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg568896%28v=vs.99%29.aspx)):

```
<li @Html.Raw(AddClasses())>tekst</li>
```